# Do not have reusble UI What to use Activity or Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am new to android I am making an  app that has a Login page fragment and with in that there is a change password option(button) and after tapping it I can create an Activity or a fragment and I dont have reusable UI as both screens are using different UI. What should I use Fragment or Activity ? To my knowledge what I know is when you have reusable UI we use fragments and fragments have faster transition than activities and with my searches I am able to find out fragments are more preferred over Activities. What is the downside if I use Activity instead of fragment if I dont have reusable UI or both are equal in this case.

Comment: If your app does support tablets and if you want efficient use of space then you can use fragments as fragments can be attached to activity

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use both `Fragment and`Activity`the only difference is that you can manage`Fragment`from one place and the`Activity`can manage individually.`Fragment` depends on you activity life cycle and each activity has its own life cycle

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why in your case you would prefer to use a Fragment over Activity. Fragments are parts of Activities that have fast transition and are particularly useful in tab layouts, different layout in landscape vs. portrait mode (in tablets) and navigation menus.

In your particular case, you (probably) will navigate to another Activity after changing the password, so I don't think your will need a Fragment per se. Also, if I understand correctly, it is the only layout in your Activity.

Comment: After changing the password my App will go to the Login Page  and then user will again type the changed password.